# JButton ActionListener in class 1, do something when ActionListener invoked in class 2

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a JButtonClass which extends JButton with an ActionListener inside its constructor. I also have a HeadClass which contains a HashMap. So, JButtonClass is used in HeadClass, which means I can't give "HeadClass headClass" as a parameter when I create JButtonClasses, right? Something about Dependency and runtime error if I recall correctly. So my question is, how can I call methods inside HeadClass when the ActionListener in JButtonClass is invoked?

EDIT: I have no way of knowing which button is pressed at the moment, that is why I would like to add the methods of HeadClass that need to be run to every ActionListener, so that no matter what JButton is pressed, that the same methods in HeadClass get called.

Comment: `"... which means I can't give "HeadClass headClass" as a parameter when I create JButtonClasses, right? "` -- no, it means nothing of the sort.

Comment: Note that it's usually better to not extend JButton, and it's almost always better to not have the button's listener be internal to the button itself. Why not simply have your HeadClass add the appropriate ActionListener to your button, one that carries a decent reference to the HeadClass itself? But regardless, for a better answer, please consider asking a more complete question, one with [mcve] code.

Comment: Doesn't it cause Class Dependency? Wouldn't it hurt the efficiency and reusability of my code?

Comment: If you're worried about that, about coupling and cohesion, then scratch this completely and aim for the M-V-C design or one of its many variants.

Comment: I'll definitely look into M-V-C, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your mindset may be reminiscent of C++. In C++, you cannot have one class inside the other inside the other, etc. as this would create a result which has infinite size. In Java, since everything is a pointer, this is fine:

```
class JButtonClass extends JButton {
    JButtonClass(HeadClass headClass) {
        headClass.jbtn = this;
        this.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                headClass.someFunction();
            } 
        });
    }
}

class HeadClass {
    HashMap hashMap;
    JButtonClass jbtn;

    void someFunction() {
        // do stuff with jbtn
    }
}

public static main(String[] args) {
    new JButtonClass(new HeadClass());
}
```